# Changing a property value from a button click in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, nullreferenceexception, razor-pages

I would like to change the value of a property in the server from a button click in ASP.NET Core Razor Page.

I have this property in a class:

```
public class MyClassViewModel
{ 
    public string ButtonColor { get; set; }
    public MyClassViewModel()
    {
        ButtonColor = new string("#007BFF");
    }

}
```

In my Razor page I am checking for a null reference exception like this:

> ```
> @{
> MyClassViewModel color = new MyClassViewModel();
> if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(color.ButtonColor))
> {
> color.ButtonColor = "#000000";
> }
> }
> ```

I have a two anchors  that save the user selected color to a hidden input. These tags allow the user to choose their desired color. It is like this:

```
<li><input type="text" id="selected-theme" value="@Model.ButtonColor" hidden readonly/></li>
<li><a style="color:rgb(7,100,199)" onclick="apply_theme('#007BFF')"><i class="fas fa-square"></i></a></li>
<li><a style="color:rgb(188,126,0)" onclick="apply_theme('#BC7E00')"><i class="fas fa-square"></i></a></li>
```

This is the script containing the 'apply_theme()' function:

```
function apply_theme(color) {
    document.getElementById('selected-theme').value = color;
}
```

The issue here is that I am getting:
`'System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.''` exception on this line:

```
<li><input type="text" id="selected-theme" value="@Model.ButtonColor" hidden readonly/></li>
```

The compiler is complaining that I have not instantiated the object before getting the value, but I think I have done so in the constructor. What am I missing, or how am I getting it all wrong?

I hope to get some insight into this scenario.

Comment: Shouldn't that be `value="@color.ButtonColor"` ?

Comment: @Mike Brind: I have tried that approach but the problem is that the value will always be "color.ButtonColor = "#000000""; I want the value to be dynamic and change when any of the anchors is clicked. If I set "value="@color.ButtonColor"" it will be as if I have hard coded the value.

Comment: You said you want to change the property value in the server side by a button click, However, what you have done is just changing the value of the element on the html page, It will not affect the model property value. You should send a request and change its value in the controller action.

Comment: @mj1313: I really appreciate your response. I tried that approach but the problem is that the click event on the anchor is sending me to that action and expects a return of a ViewResult. I want to stay on the same page while changing the property value on the server, without leaving the current page. If possible you could show me or explain further how to achieve this. If my entire approach is wrong I am open for much more cleaner approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a simple working demo. I used the partial view.

**Index View:**

```
<li id="theme"></li>

<li><a style="color:rgb(7,100,199)" onclick="apply_theme('#007BFF')"><i class="fas fa-square">theme1</i></a></li>

<li><a style="color:rgb(188,126,0)" onclick="apply_theme('#BC7E00')"><i class="fas fa-square">theme2</i></a></li>

@section scripts{ 

<script>
    $(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "get",
            url: "/Home/SetColor",
            success: function (result) {
                $("#theme").html(result);
            }
        })
    })

    function apply_theme(color) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "get",
            url: "/Home/SetColor",
            data: { color: color },
            success: function (result) {
                $("#theme").html(result);
            }
        })
    }
</script>
}
```

**SetColor:**

```
public IActionResult SetColor(string color)
{
    MyClassViewModel myClassViewModel = new MyClassViewModel();
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(color))
    {
        myClassViewModel.ButtonColor = color;
    }
    return PartialView(myClassViewModel);
}
```

**Partial View:**

```
@model MyClassViewModel

<input type="text" id="selected-theme" value="@Model.ButtonColor" readonly />
```

**Result:**

[image]